# PLS coefficients with r

Tags: r

I'm making a PLS model using packages "pls" and "ChemometricswithR". I'm able to perform the model but I have a problem. I did a leave-one-out validation and if I ask for the coefficients I can see only an equation (I suppose the average of all the equations developed in leave one out validation).

Is there a way to see all  the "n" equations (where n is the number of the observations in my matrix) with all the slopes coefficients?

this is the model i used: mod2<-plsr(SH_uve~matrix_uve,ncomp=11, data=dataset_uve, validation="LOO",jackknife = TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to answer if you gave more information, how you are calling the functions etc? Based on what you said you are doing I'm assuming you are using the functions `crossval()` and `PCA()` from packages "pls" and "ChemometricswithR" respectively. I'm not familiar with these functions but the documentations sates that for coefficients *"(only if
jackknife is TRUE) an array with the jackknifed regression coefficients.The dimensions correspond to the predictors, responses, number of components, and segments, respectively"*. So I would say make sure `jackknife=TRUE` and that you are specifying the correct number of segments in `crossval()`. If you are using different functions you should edit your question and add in the relevant information.

Comment: I used this function

mod2<-plsr(SH_uve~matrix_uve,ncomp=11, data=dataset_uve, validation="LOO",jackknife = TRUE)

I didn't use crossval().....in you opinion what should i do? crossval with 206 segments (my observations)? I don't understand what a segment is in the crossval() function...

Comment: Ok, looking over those functions it seems there is some overlap. The description for crossval states A “stand alone” cross-validation function for mvr objects and they provide this example for crossval `yarn.cv <- crossval(yarn.pcr, segments = 10)` where `yarn.pcr <- pcr(density ~ msc(NIR), 6, data = yarn)`. So maybe try `crossval(mod2, segments=206, jackknife=TRUE)` and keep looking through the documentation there might be a better way of doing what you want.

Comment: ok i tried. I used: crossval(mod2,segments=206,jackknife=TRUE) and this error appears: 

Error in dimnames(cvCoef) <- c(dimnames(coef(object)), list(paste("Seg",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [3] not equal to array extent

Comment: Not sure but maybe segments # is wrong. Make sure all your inputs are correct.

Comment: ;( no, without jackknife=TRUE the crossval()works....really, i don't understand this error.

Comment: OK, i found the solution (i hope). mod2<plsr(SH_uve~matrix_uve,ncomp=11,data=dataset_uve,validation="LOO",jackknife = TRUE)
The matrix with coefficients is inside "validation" in the mvr array....so,

coefficients<-mod2$validation$coefficients[,,11,]

However TY CCurtis, you helped me so much.

Comment: Glad you were able to find something that works. Once you're sure you have the correct solution you should post it as an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found the solution.

The model i used is:

```
mod2<plsr(SH_uve~matrix_uve,ncomp=11,data=dataset_uve,validation="LOO",jackknife = TRUE)
```

The coefficients matrix is inside the mod2 array. I called the matrix with the command:

`coefficients<-mod2$validation$coefficients[,,11,]` and i obtained the coefficients matrix for all the equations used in the leave-one-out cross validation.